# How to calculate confidence intervals in a subgroup of a weighted sample?

Tags: confidence-interval, sample, weights, weighted-data, subset

I have a weighted data sample (size : 20000) and I want to calculate a 95% confidence interval for the mean of a variable in the dataset, but only in a specific subgroup within this dataset (size of the subgroup : 200).

The values of the weighted mean and the weighted variance in this specific subgroup are given.

Thus, I can use the traditional formula : $I = \left[\bar{X_w} - 1.96 \frac{\sqrt{V_w}}{\sqrt{n}}, \bar{X_w} + 1.96 \frac{\sqrt{V_w}}{\sqrt{n}}\right] $ where $\bar{X_w}$ is the weighted mean and $\bar{V_w}$ is the weighted variance.

However, what $n$ do I need to choose ? The size of my complete sample (20000) or the size of my subgroup within the sample (200) ? The results are (logically) very different depending on what $n$ I choose.

Comment: Can you describe the sample design? Given that you're working with weights, I presume it's not a simple random sample which would suggest that you can't take a subgroup and analyze it as if the subgroup was a simple random sample.

Comment: This is a survey carried out among individuals, and weights have been calibrated to the known distribution of the general population in terms of age and gender, among other variables. I do not precisely know how people were selected, but it wasn't completely random. My subgroup is the part of the sample living in a certain region.